# Find the spinach that everyone eats

Tags: riddle

> 1. Most of my friends are black.
> 2. I am someones strength while someone is my strength and we all are dependent on each other.
> 3. I have a tail. Sometimes long sometimes short.
> 4. I have two teeth.
> 5. I am a spinach for rich and for poor.
> 6. Things might stop if I do not exist.
> 7. Some of us glow in dark.
> 8. Before you start guessing, just to let you know,    You need to be aware of me.

So, find the spinach that everyone eats.

Update#1

Hint#1

> Spinach is a metaphor. "Everyone" are non living things.

Comment: Does it involves languages other then English?

Comment: What do you mean by "spinach"? Is it a substitution for another word? Is it a metaphor?

Comment: @Alex - Its English. No other language.

Comment: @Leafy Green- Updated

Comment: is it abstract like 'electricity' or material like 'charging cord' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer -

> I am a cellphone charger
>  [image]

Most of my friends are black.

> Yes, most of them are black shows a single search result
>  [image]

I am someones strength while someone is my strength and we all are dependent on each other.

> I give power/strength to the cell phones and the electricity gives power/strength to me

I have a tail. Sometimes long sometimes short.

> Self explanatory

I have two teeth.

> Again self explanatory.
>
>  [image]

I am a spinach for rich and for poor.

> I provide power to both cheaper and costlier cell phones.

Things might stop if I do not exist.

> Self explanatory. No battery no cell phones.

Some of us glow in dark.

> [image]

You need to be aware of me.

> [image]

Comment: In some parts of the world, you have three teeth.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's

> a watch/hands of a watch

Most of my friends are black

> When I think of clock hands I imagine them black and most of them are black I think

I am someones strength while someone is my strength and we all are dependent on each other

> Could be a reference to time and work. You get money for work/time and we depend on time to finish tasks

I have a tail. Sometimes long sometimes short.

> A pocket watch with a chain. Or a grandfather clock

I have two teeth

> One hand for hours and one for minutes. Some even have one for seconds

I am a spinach for rich and for poor.

> Could be a hint towards "spin" as the hands of a clock are spinning. Also time is the same for rich and poor

Things might stop if I do not exist.

> Again, time.

Some of us glow in dark.

> I've seen watches with hands that can glow in the night. There are some special colours which can do that

Comment: Good one. But it's not the One!

Comment: I have added a hint. Spinach is a metaphor. Hence your answer goes void. Things might stop if I do not exist"- You answered watch but here you are using Time. Again false.

Comment: Also, when I say "most" it means most.. Warches are not black mostly. Steel watches are hardly black. So this is again false.

Answer (score -2):

Is it

> SUN

Most of my friends are black.

> Friends here could be people more exposed to sun. They get tanned and are black.

I am someones strength while someone is my strength and we all are dependent on each other.

> Sun helps with Vitamin D necessary for bones and hence strength.

I have a tail. Sometimes long sometimes short.

> Could be the rays.

I have two teeth.

> Not sure.

I am a spinach for rich and for poor.

> Spinach here could refer to energy source like for Popeye. So, SUN is a source of energy.

Things might stop if I do not exist.

> For sure.

Some of us glow in dark.

> Since, sun is a star and considering one location, some stars can be seen in the dark glowing while SUN will be absent.